# Quit Ubuntu Application by "clicking" the x-Button via Terminal

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, pkill

I am trying to quit a program with a bash script. The problem is that it has to be quit via the the x-button to save some settings. So `pkill program` do not work in my case. I know that I have to sent a signal for the x-button but I can not find witch one.

Comment: pkill sends the exactly same signal as X button. (SIGTERM 15)

Comment: Well when I quit the application by clicking the X button my settings are save. When I quit it via pkill they are not save.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85205/187122.